# Azure Istio - Revision asm-1-17 is not supported by the service mesh add-on

Tags: azure, kubernetes, istio

I am trying to activate istio in my azure kubernetes cluster, with the following command:

```
az aks mesh enable --resource-group rgtest01 --name akstest01
```

I am getting the error message:

> (BadRequest) Requested change in revisions is not allowed. Reason:
> Revision asm-1-17 is not supported by the service mesh add-on. Code:
> BadRequest Message: Requested change in revisions is not allowed.
> Reason: Revision asm-1-17 is not supported by the service mesh add-on.

My azure kubernetes cluster is running with the version 1.26.3.

Does anybody know how to activate the mesh without getting an error message? Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**
We upgraded the kubernetes cluster to the version 1.28.5 and now its working.

Thanks for all the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue you can fix it with the command:

```
az extension add -n aks-preview
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to enable preview, specifically set the revision.

`az aks mesh enable --name $env:CLUSTER --resource-group $env:RESOURCE_GROUP --revision "asm-1-19"`